# Falta el archivo “kernel-qemu” - AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin.android, avd

Estoy tratando de iniciar un dispositivo virtual en AVD Manager y note que el problema se presenta con los dispositivos mayores al Android 6.0(API 23).

Estoy trabajando con Xamarin.Android (Visual Studio) y el dispositivo que me necesito iniciar es uno con Android 8.1(API 27 Intel Atom x86) pero al tratar de iniciarlo me dice que el archivo "kernel-qemu" no esta en la carpeta de la imagen.

Error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Ocho'
    emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
    emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\) but cannot find kernel file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\\system-images\ sub directories
```

Revise la carpeta donde debería estar y solo esta uno que se llama "kernel-ranchu-64", ya he intentado cosas como renombrar el "ranchu" por "qemu" pero no funciona.

Ya no se que mas intentar.
¿Alguien tiene ese archivo kernel-qemu que me pueda compartir para hacer funcionar el emulador?
[image: error]

---------------------- Información Adicional -----------------

Asi me aparece el SDK Manager

[image: SDK_IMAGEN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intente de todo pero no pude solucionar el error en el SDK Manager.

Lo solucione utilizando las máquinas virtuales de **Genymotion** (Oracle VM).

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar la imagen "ARM EABI v7a" desde el [SDK manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)

> **Instalación de imágenes del sistema**
>
> Según los niveles de API de Android a los que desea dirigirse, debe
>   descargar e instalar las imágenes del sistema específicas del nivel de
>   API que usa el emulador de Android SDK. Para cada nivel de API de
>   Android, hay un conjunto de imágenes del sistema x86 que deberá
>   descargar e instalar para crear dispositivos virtuales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esto en la [**documentación de Xamarin.**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/android-sdk-emulator/configuration-and-use/)

Comment: Checa la información adicional que agregue ahorita. Asi me aparece a mi.